# PHP - Long polling, page keeps loading

Tags: javascript, php, long-polling

I don't understand why, but the loop in my PHP file requested by my ajax code makes my browser freeze when loading a page

PHP code :

```js
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ignore_user_abort(false);

$isUptodate = (bool) file_get_contents($this->uptodateFile);

while ($isUptodate === true)
{
  sleep(1);
  $isUptodate = (bool) file_get_contents($this->uptodateFile);
}

$updateUptodateFile = fopen($this->uptodateFile, 'w');
fwrite($updateUptodateFile, 'true'); // when something is inserted into my db, the file contains a false value

$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->updateFile), true);

echo json_encode(['updates' => count($jsonData)]);
```

JS code :

```js
    checkForUpdates: function ()
    {
      var that = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'updates.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000,
      }).done(function (data)
      {
        console.log('Went OK');
        if (data.updates)
        {
          alert('there is new!');
          setTimeout(function () { that.checkForUpdates() }, 5000);
        }
      }).fail(function (data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        setTimeout(function () { that.checkForUpdates() }, 10000);
      });
    }
```

Do you know where it goes wrong? It's weird because default ajax async parameter is true, so it shouldn't freeze my browser...

Comment: Is only your browser freezing? Or your whole system? If it's only your browser, something must be wrong in your JS. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I think it is the whole system since if I remove the loop, browser won't freeze. Console doesn't show anything wrong

Comment: Does stuff break if you request just an empty PHP file?

Comment: it seems not, ajax will just go to the fail statement since it didn't receive a json

Comment: It looks like you have an endless loop once the file contains 'true'. I'm not sure how that freezes anything since you added a sleep, but I can imagine you were expecting output instead of nothing?

Comment: Well I think it is the spirit of long polling... Go in an endless loop until it finds a "false" value in my file and then return something to my ajax request. A timeout on ajax request was here not to overload the server charge. I was expecting the loop not to end until it finds something in my file, but I didn't think it would make my browser freeze since it is supposed to be an asynchronous request

Comment: You said it makes not only your browser freeze, but your whole system. Usually that means there's something going wrong in your PHP, especially since the request is done asynchronously. It's weird that your system freezes, since you have that sleep there, but you indeed appear to be going to an endless loop (issue a `break;` when you want to break it).